# SQL stored procedure not returning all SELECT statements

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an `SQLReader` [which would like to get multiple table results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2971475/1305911) of a stored procedure from SQL server.

SP currently built on multiple `SELECT` statements.

The reader seems to be working OK, but out of 4 results I can only see 2. Seems to be related to the order of the `SELECT`s, because when I change the order I get a different pair out of all result tables, but it's not necessarily the same two.

**e.g.**

```
`SELECT` are ordered `1-2-3-4` I get `4 & 2` (in that order)

`SELECT` are ordered `2-1-3-4` I get `3 & 2` (in that order)

`SELECT` are ordered `2-1-4-3` I get `3 & 1` (in that order)
```

My question is, relating to linked question above, what should the SP look like?

**Additionally**

Incidentally, I tried

```
`2-1-3-4-1-2-3-4` to get `3-1-4-2` (in that order)
```

It works, but it's silly.

Comment: A series of standard `SELECT` statements in a stored procedure, not even delineated by a separator, should work. You then need to make sure you allow MARS on your connections and that your reader is advancing the result-set.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, that's what I have... They're actually in `BEGIN...END` blocks, not that it should make a difference. Removing blocks, adding `;`, nothing changed. Neither did adding `MultipleActiveResultSets=true;` to the connection string...

Comment: That connection string change will be needed (I think), but then in your data reader you need to `NextResult` to get the result-set from the next `SELECT` statement. I couldn't say why it only returns some of the sets and not all or one, not without a complete example to debug with.

Comment: Is it a must to use `SQLReader`? Can you try with a `DataSet`? After you get the DataSet, you can easily access DataTables contained in the DataSet like dataset.Tables[0]...

Comment: @NP3 Doesn't have to be, but a `DataSet` will use one under the hood. I don't have enough experience with `DataSet` types because I've always leaned towards readers.

Comment: Multiple selects in a single batch is still a single batch so does not require MARS

Comment: @NP3, that was the way to go - thanks!

Comment: @AlexK. Ah yeah, apologies. I always get confused with MARS and simply reading multiple results.